# How to add a custom add-in in Microsoft outlook Professional plus 2013?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

i am currently developing an **outlook add-in using office-js**. i tested it in outlook 365 , outlook 2016 and in the web version and it works good. but when trying to add it (to add the manifest file) in the company outlook ( Microsoft outlook Professional plus 2013 ) . i can't find the **Manage Add-ins button on the Info tab.** following this article.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing#outlook-2013

is there any way to add the manifest file in the outlook client of 2013 version

Comment: Did you configure an Exchange account in Outlook? Web add-ins work with Exchange profiles only.

Comment: What Eugene said is correct, you need to have an Exchange account to use add-ins. If you do have that set up but it's still not working, something else to try is to add your add-in through Outlook on the Web.